# Create directory if zip archive contains several files

Tags: zip

If an archive contains several files in the root directory, I'd like to create
a directory named after the file name (without extension). If an archive
contains just a directory, then I'd like to simply extract it. Assume I have
the following archive:

```
# file: withdir.zip
somedir/alpha
somedir/beta
somedir/gamma
```

If I extract it in the current directory I'd like to have it simply extracted
(`unzip withdir.zip`):

```
somedir/alpha
somedir/beta
somedir/gamma
```

Now assume the following archive:

```
# file: nodir.zip
alpha
beta
gamma
```

When I run `unzip nodir.zip` I end up cluttering the current directory
with the three files:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
```

I'd rather run `unzip -d nodir nodir.zip`:

```
nodir/alpha
nodir/beta
nodir/gamma
```

If I use nautilus and right click on “Extract Here”. It behaves exactly as it
should. But unfortunately I haven't found a command line switch for `unzip` or
`7z` which yield the same behaviour. How to achieve that? Are there other tools I can use instead
(no GUI)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like this (zsh syntax):

```
unz() (
  tmp=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -d -- ${${argv[-1]:t:r}%.tar}.XXXXXX) || exit
  print -r >&2 "Extracting in $tmp"
  cd -- $tmp || exit
  [[ $argv[-1] = /* ]] || argv[-1]=../$argv[-1]
  (set -x; "$@"); ret=$?
  files=(*(ND[1,2]))
  case $#files in
    (0) print -r >&2 "No file created"
        rmdir -v "../$tmp";;
    (1) mv -v -- $files .. && rmdir -v ../$tmp;;
    (*) mv -vT ../$tmp ../$tmp:r;;
  esac && exit $ret
)
```

That is:

1. create a directory in anycase
2. run the command
3. depending on how many files the command generated:

   - remove that directory (if it didn't create any file)
   - if it created only one file/dir, move it one level up and discard our directory
   - otherwise, attempt to strip the random string from the end of our temp directory.

This way, you can do:

```
unz unzip foo.zip
unz tar xf foo.tar.gz
```

It assumes that the last argument to the extracting command is the file to extract. It also assumes GNU tools  for the `-v` options. On non-GNU systems, you can remove those and possibly do the logging by hand. `mv -T` is also GNU specific, and is to force `mv` to attempt do a rename only.

Answer (score 3):

As `unzip` and `7z` both have a switch to output to a given directory, you can create a simple script, that checks, how many files are in the root of the archive and then adds the switch if needed.

With 7z this is easier, as it has the `-slt` switch, which makes the output more machine-readable. For every file in the zip, the output will contain a `Path = ...` line. Files in the root should not contain any `/` in the value.

A simple script I wrote to unpack files that way:

```
#!/bin/sh
for archive in "$@"; do
    # count files in root dir
    rootfiles=$(7z l -slt "${archive}" | grep -c 'Path = [^/]*$')

    # add -o switch, if more than one file in root
    # checks for >2, because path of the zip file itself is listed too
    if [ $rootfiles -gt 2 ]; then
        filename=${archive##*/}
        rootname=${filename%.*}
        opt="-o${rootname}"
    fi

    #unpack
    7z x "${opt}" "${archive}"
done
```

Edit: script now works with zip too

Comment: This script doesn't work as expected. It creates a directory `withdir` for the archive `withdir.zip` although it contains just one directory in the root because `grep -c "Folder = -"` returns `3`.

Comment: ah, Folder seems to be different for zip files. I'll look for a fix

Comment: @Marco: I changed the script and tested it with zip files, it now only creates the folder when needed

Answer (score 3):

[patool](http://wummel.github.io/patool/) handles different kinds of archives and creates a subdirectory in case the archive contains multiple files to prevent cluttering the working directory with the extracted files.

#### Create archive

```
patool create archive.zip somedirectory
```

#### Extract archive

```
patool extract archive.zip
```

To obtain a list of the supported formats, use `patool formats`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [unar](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline), which creates a containing directory by default when there are two or more top-level files:

```
$ touch 1 2
$ zip a.zip 1 2
  adding: 1 (stored 0%)
  adding: 2 (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l a.zip
Archive:  a.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  04-29-14 10:56   1
        0  04-29-14 10:56   2
 --------                   -------
        0                   2 files
$ unar a.zip
a.zip: Zip
  1  (0 B)... OK.
  2  (0 B)... OK.
Successfully extracted to "a".
$ ls a
1 2
```

Add `-d` to always create a containing directory.