# tar extract into directory with same base name?

Tags: tar

I have a zipped file like `myArchive123.tar.gz`. Inside, it contains a folder like `helloWorld`

If I extract it with `tar -xf myArchive123.tar.gz`, I get the `helloWorld` folder:

```
ls 
myArchive123.tar.gz
helloWorld
```

I want the output to be the same as the file name minus the `.tar.gz` extension. I.e.:

```
tar <magic paramaters> myArchive123.tar.gz 
ls 
 myArchive123.tar.gz
 myArchive123
cd myArchive123
ls 
  helloWorld
```

Can this be done?

- I never know what's inside the archive. It could be a folder, could be many files.
- I'd be ok with using another tool if tar can't do it.
- I'd be ok with a longer form that can be turned into a script

**EDIT**
In the meantime, I wrote myself a script that seems to get the job done (see my posted answer below).
The main thing is that it should be packageable into a one-liner like:

```
extract <file>
```

Comment: Does the archive always contain exactly one folder?

Comment: See [Create directory if zip archive contains several files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72313/12779)

Comment: I don't know what's inside it at extraction time. This shouldn't depend on what's inside the archive either. If it's a folder, extract the folder in there. if it's a file, extract all files.

Comment: In the mean time I pieced together a script (see below). I can accept the answer only in 2 days thou.

Comment: Will the archive ever contain more than one folder at the top level?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I mentioned in the question, we don't know what's inside the archive.

Comment: They should be inside a folder that matches the archive name minus the file extension. Like "Extract here" functionality in windows.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Actually no, a tar may contain many files/directories, I came here because I came across calibre tar file, when you extract it, it put all its directories/files into the current directory, then I have to remove them all and extract them into one single directory, so it's better to check the tar file first in a script or in the command line.

Comment: @CodyChan Sure, and I asked because if the tar file contains multiple directories and more than one of the directories contains, say, a `README` file, the solution becomes more complicated (if you don't want to lose data).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `gnu tar`, you could use `--xform` (or `--transform`) to prepend `/prefix/` to each file name:

```
tar -xf myArchive.tar.gz --xform='s|^|myArchive/|S'
```

note there's no leading `/` in `prefix/` and the `sed` expression ends with `S` to exclude symbolic link targets from file name transformations.
To test it (dry-run):

```
tar -tf myArchive.tar.gz --xform='s|^|myArchive/|S' --verbose --show-transformed-names
```

---

To get you started, here's a very simplistic script that you could invoke as `extract <file>`:

```
STRIP=${1%.*}                                #strip last suffix
NAME=${STRIP%.tar}                           #strip .tar suffix, if present
tar -xf "$1" --xform="s|^|$NAME/|S"          #run command
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, with exception that I'd like to be able to package it into something like: extract <file>

Comment: This is buggy, it stops at first dot. E.g I have a file like this: eclipse-SDK-4.5M6-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz   I expect an output without the .tar.gz, but I get eclipse-sdk-4

Comment: In the script above I strip the extension and strip it further if I find a 'tar'.

Comment: In general, with many types of archives. I was hoping for a quick one-liner, I thought maybe I was missing some argument flag. But it seems that there is no trivial solution to this?

Comment: Good stuff. This works and is shorter than the script I wrote. Nice!

Answer (score 16):

```console
$ tar -xf myArchive123.tar.gz --one-top-level
```

**--one-top-level**[=DIR] 
Extract all files into DIR, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory named by the base name of the archive (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable by --auto-compress).

Answer (score 14):

Well, you could do it in a couple of steps at least.  If you did

```
mkdir <archive name>
tar -xf <archive name>.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C <archive name>
```

that would accomplish the task, though there may be a more compact answer out there yet.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

The accepted answer is shorter than the below. (do the same thing, but shorter is usually better).

---

I eventually hacked myself a script for the task at hand. it works with .tar .tar.gz and .gz

```
#!/bin/sh
#usage:
# nameOfScript myArchive.tar.gz
# nameOfScript myArchive.gz
# nameOfScript myArchive.tar
#
# Result:
# myArchive   //folder
fileName="${1%.*}" #extracted filename

#handle the case of archive.tar.gz
trailingExtension="${fileName##*.}"
if [ "$trailingExtension" == "tar" ]  
then
    fileName="${fileName%.*}"  #remove trailing  tar.
fi

mkdir "$fileName"
tar -xf "$1" --strip-components=0 -C "$fileName"
```

Usage:

```
   nameOfScript archive.tar.gz 
   ls 
    archive
   cd archive 
   ls 
    <archive content>
```

Note, this solution is capable of dots in a file name. E.g Eclipse-4.5M-SDK.tar.gz.

I keep the script in my git repo. For the latest version, see: 
https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/ldts/blob/master/pathscripts/leo-tar-here

Answer (score 2):

One more possible solution is using `--transform` option:

```
tar -xzf ARCHIVE_NAME.tgz --transform="s/OLD_DIR_NAME/ARCHIVE_NAME/"
```

With your files:

```
tar -xzf myArchive123.tar.gz --transform="s/helloWorld/myArchive123/"
```

Comment: but this pre-supposes that you know what's inside the archive

Comment: e.g how would I turn this into a one-line script without knowing what's inside the archive?

Comment: You're correct. It's only one possible solution as I wrote here...

Comment: is there any difference between that and --strip-compoments=0 myArchive123?

Comment: It processes the files/directories names and changes it using regexp. Good idea with `--xform`!

Comment: And `--strip-components=0` simply removes the first directory name from the path and with `-C` option stores de-archived files into the new directory.